# Trying to create sorting code with 3 trackbar values using the if command in c#

Tags: c#

I have to create a windows form with(c#),

- 3 trackbars
- 1 button
- 1 label

Using the if and else if commands.
My problem is,
I cant get the end result to show up in label1.
I did manage to display them in labels2-4. But this is not the way to go for this assignment.

here's the code.

```
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        trackBar1.Maximum = 10;
        trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        trackBar2.Maximum = 10;
        trackBar2.Minimum = 0;
        trackBar3.Maximum = 10;
        trackBar3.Minimum = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;

        a = Convert.ToInt32 (trackBar1.Value);
        b = Convert.ToInt32 (trackBar2.Value);
        c = Convert.ToInt32 (trackBar3.Value);

        int d;
        int E;
        int f;

        if ((a < b) && (a < c)&& (b> c))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = a);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = c);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = b);
            label1.Text =Convert.ToString (string d,e,f);
        }
        if ((a < b) && (a < c) && (b < c))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = a);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = b);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = c);
        }
        else if ((a > c) && (a > b) && (b > c))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = c);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = b);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = a);
        }
        else if ((a < c) && (a > b) && (b > c))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = c);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = a);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = b);
        }
        else if ((b < a) && (b < c) && (c > a))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = b);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = a);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = c);
        }
        else if ((b < a) && (b < c) && (c < a))
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d = b);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(E = c);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(f = a);
        }
    }
```

I need label1.Text to be the result of labels 2-4, I tried this label1.Text= Convert.ToString(d = b + E = c + f = a) and I tried replacing the + with , but that wont work either. I think I have to use a string format but I wouldn't know how and if its needed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?  I would put this below your if statements so it's called under every condition.

```
label1.Text = (int.Parse(label2.Text) + int.Parse(label4.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: almost, I have to remove the other labels. Cant just make em invisible. But thanks, I was looking or methods to get that all in ma label 1. totally forgot about ToString.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the contents of the labels `label2, label3, label4` together to be shown in `label1`? Put after your ifs the line

```
label1.Text = d.ToString() + " " + E.ToString() + " " + f.ToString();
```

Comment: Long live the king, this was exactly what I was looking for. Totally forgot about ToString.

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating string it is better to use string.Format

In your case it will be

```
label1.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", d,E,f);
```